# Using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus with SAS token in netstandard2 project

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, .net-standard

The `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` package allows to connect to Azure via SAS tokens. Microsoft recommends to use the newer package `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` instead:

[image]

But I couldn't find a way to create a `ServiceBusClient` with the help of a SAS token.

Is there a way to create a `ServiceBusClient` with a SAS token and if yes: how. If not: What is the recommended way to connect to Azure via SAS token? Do I have to use the outdated `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus` package? There is a third package named `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` but it seems that this one needs a .NET Framework project and does not work with .NET Standard?

Note: We cannot use the authentication via Azure.Identity because the users who should get access to the service bus are not part of our Azure AD and never will.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a SAS token with the `ServiceBusClient` can be done by adding your SAS token to the connection string, using the pattern `SharedAccessSignature=<<SAS>>;` and removing the `SharedAccessKey` and `SharedAccessKeyName` tokens that the portal populates.

In the 7.2.x-beta line, a SAS token can also be specified by using the constructor that accepts an `AzureSasCredential`:

```cs
var credential = new AzureSasCredential("<< YOUR SAS TOKEN >>");

var fullyQualifiedNamespace = 
    "<< NAMESPACE (likely similar to {your-namespace}.servicebus.windows.net) >>";

await using var client = new ServiceBusClient(fullyQualifiedNamespace, credential);
```

If you're able to make use of the beta, I'd recommend using the credential, as it allows you to update the SAS token without creating a new client, which the connection string approach does not support.

With respect to libraries, `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` is the current generation and we'd recommend using it over the two legacy libraries that you've mentioned.

Comment: What is the replacement of [CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.tokenprovider.createsharedaccesssignaturetokenprovider?view=azure-dotnet) as a way to build the SAS token?

Comment: Rotating the token is done by calling the [Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.azuresascredential.update?view=azure-dotnet#azure-azuresascredential-update(system-string)) method on `AzureSasCredential`, which is safe to call while the client is in use.   There's no SDK type for generating a SAS token; [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token) is the official documentation for doing so and provides examples for a number of languages.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response!, Do  you know the replacement for `ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder `?

Comment: To parse a connection string, [ServiceBusConnectionStringProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusconnectionstringproperties?view=azure-dotnet) can be used.  There is no included support for building a connection string.  Generally, the client libraries in the Azure SDK attempt to support connection strings as copy/paste values from the Azure portal and discourage attempting to mutate them or build them directly.

Comment: Thanks again Jesse!